# Divide by zero error encountered when using datediff

Tags: sql, datediff

I receive this error while using this query. Is there a way to prevent this error?

This is the error

> Divide by zero error encountered.

Here is the query:

```
UPDATE T_SG_WICA_RISK_DETAILS   
SET EarnedPercentage =  case when Policy_ExpiryDate <  (getdate()-1) then '1'
                else datediff(day, Policy_EffectiveDate,(getdate()-1)) /
datediff(day, Policy_EffectiveDate,Policy_ExpiryDate)
                end
```

Comment: Please only tag the RDBMS you are *really* using. SQL Server and MySQL are completely different products. As for the error, it is telling you the problem; what about the error don't you understand here?

Comment: I'd guess you have a row with effective date and a expiry date on the same day, so the date diff in your divisor returns zero

Comment: @Larnu Got it. As for the error, I'm not sure how to solve it as the divisor shouldn't return zero. I've looked at a few other threads on this, but I'm still not sure.

Comment: As, @DaveSmith mentioned, the division would be `0` when `Policy_EffectiveDate` and `Policy_ExpiryDate` are the same date. Clearly there is *at least* one row were this is true.

Comment: @Larnu @DaveSmith Alright, it appears that there are rows where `Policy_EffectiveDate` and `Policy_ExpiryDate` are the same date. NULLIF at the divisor solves the problem. Thanks

Comment: [Why should I tag my DBMS](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on your requirements and schema, you can treat such values as `NULL`

```
UPDATE T_SG_WICA_RISK_DETAILS   
SET EarnedPercentage = case
  when Policy_ExpiryDate <  (getdate()-1) then '1'
  else datediff(day, Policy_EffectiveDate,(getdate()-1)) /
    NULLIF(datediff(day, Policy_EffectiveDate,Policy_ExpiryDate), 0)
end
```

Note the `NULLIF()` in the divisor. It will produce `NULL` when the `DATEDIFF` produces the value `0` and since arithmetic expressions containing `NULL` will yield to `NULL`, your division will end up being `NULL`.

Using the above, you can have any value if `NULL` as a result is not useful by wrapping the whole expression in the `ELSE` into an `ISNULL()`:

```
UPDATE T_SG_WICA_RISK_DETAILS   
SET EarnedPercentage = case
  when Policy_ExpiryDate <  (getdate()-1) then '1'
  else ISNULL(datediff(day, Policy_EffectiveDate,(getdate()-1)) /
    NULLIF(datediff(day, Policy_EffectiveDate,Policy_ExpiryDate), 0), 0)
end
```